# Need to fetch Id of the selected record

Tags: lightning-web-components

**I need to fix the id of selected record which comes in this.selectedRBId,but it changes to the id of other record as soon as I select lastname from other record as seen in the screenshot below.How to make this.selectedRBId unique for id field?**
[image]

*child.js*

```
import { LightningElement,track,api } from 'lwc';
export default class HelloWebComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api fieldname;
    @track fieldvalue;
    @api objrec;
    @track recordId;
    
    connectedCallback(){
      this.fieldvalue = this.objrec[this.fieldname];
      this.recordId = this.objrec["Id"];
    }

    getSelectedValues(event){
      //custom event
      const passEvent = new CustomEvent('fieldselection', {
          detail:{selectedValue : this.fieldvalue, selectedField : this.fieldname, selectedrecordId : this.recordId}
      });
      this.dispatchEvent(passEvent);
    }
}
```

*child.html*

```
<template>
    <div >
        <input
        id={fieldname}
        type="radio"
        name={fieldname}
        style="margin-right: 5px"
        onclick={getSelectedValues}
        />
        {fieldvalue}
    </div>
</template>
```

*parent.js*

```
@track selectedRBValues = [];
@track selectedRBId;

onFieldSelection(event){
        this.selectedRBId = event.detail.selectedrecordId;
        console.log('this.selectedRBId: ' + this.selectedRBId);
        this.selectedRBValues.push(event.detail.selectedValue);
        console.log('this.selectedRBValues: ' + this.selectedRBValues);
        
    }
```

*parent.html*

```
 <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
              <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Field Names">Field Names</div>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <template for:each={listOfField} for:item="con">
            <tbody key={con}>
              <tr key={con}>
                <th style="height: 25px">
                  <div>{con}</div>
                </th>

                <template for:each={listOfObjects} for:item="item">

                  <th key={item} class="" scope="col" data-key={item}>
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title={item.con}>
                      <c-child-record-component objrec={item} fieldname={con} onfieldselection={onFieldSelection}></c-child-record-component>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                </template>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </template>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the value of `selectedField` on the incoming event, like this (in `parent.js`):

```js
onFieldSelection(event){
    if (event.detail.selectedField === "Id") {
        this.selectedRBId = event.detail.selectedrecordId;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked!